# Running Display in textarea - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I was wondering how to keep outputs saved in the textarea box.. 
I'm writing a javascript program to translate english words to pig latin, so hello would be ellhay. 
Anyways, say I type in "are" and in the textarea it translates it to "reaay" and then I type in "hello" (translation "ellohay") the textarea should output "ellohay" and "reaay" under it

I've tried this (edit now trying with array called outputs):

```
function printLatinWord() { 
    <!--
        var outputs = new Array(); 
var input = document.form.english.value;
    var lowercase = input.toLowerCase();
        var fininput = lowercase.split (" ");
    var output = ""; 

for (i = 0; i < fininput.length; i++) { 
    var result = fininput[i]; 
    output += result.substring (1, result.length) + result.substring(0,1) + "ay ";
    document.form.piglat.value = output + "\n"; 
    var j = 0;
    output = outputs[j];
    j++;

}
    /* 
var newtext = "\n"; 
document.form.piglat.value = newtext + document.form.piglat.value;
   //trying to keep running display of conversions 
var newtext = ("\n");
output += newtext;*/

}
```

Basically nothing new happens with
At the end the var **newtext** is supposed to be where the outputs are stored.. but I'm not sure exactly how to get the values from the textarea and keep them there to be displayed *under* new outputs, if that makes sense.

Comment: I would just add the `"\n"` onto the end of your output variable. `document.form.piglat.value = output + "\n";`

Comment: @MarkWalters that didn't do anything :( it just displays the new output everytime

Comment: `<!--` inside a function? Really? HTML comments in script elements are [a cargo cult practice](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/) at the best of times, but that isn't even the right place for them!

Comment: Try `document.form.piglat.value = document.form.piglat.value + output + "\n"`

Comment: wish i could mark a comment as an answer lol

Answer (score 0):

`document.form.piglat.value += newtext;` appends `newtext` to the existing value. If you want it *prepended* instead, use

`document.form.piglat.value = newtext + document.form.piglat.value;`

Comment: i tried that.. and now its just showing the same word twice or there's a blank line then it displays the word, here's my adjusted code 
`for (i = 0; i < fininput.length; i++) { 
    var result = fininput[i]; 
    output += result.substring (1, result.length) + result.substring(0,1) + "ay ";
    document.form.piglat.value = output;     
} 
var newtext = "\n"; 
document.form.piglat.value = newtext + document.form.piglat.value;`